# Linqpad can not find subclassed DbContext

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linqpad

Assembly A:
    `public class CommonDataContext : DbContext {}`

Assembly B:
    `public class CustomDataContext : CommonDataContext {}`

Trying to open context from Assembly B using Linqpad, it gives "There are no types based on `System.Data.Entity.DbContext` in that assembly."

This makes sense as I'm assuming Linqpad only does a reflection for classes which directly implement `DbContext`.

If only C# supported multiple inheritance?

My questions are: Is there a workaround? Is this a known limitation? Is there a user-voice item for this support?

Thanks

Comment: I'd start with mailing linqpad with the quesiton... and then let us know :)

Comment: Might be a silly question, but have you added Assembly A as a reference in addition to B?